# Google Calendar: Quick Add Format

Tags: google-calendar

I am writing a script to send an email to my Google account which will in turn trigger IFTTT and use Google Calendar's Quick Add function to add the body of the email to my calendar. I seem to be having problems figuring out the correct format the entries need to be in order for quick add to correctly add an event.
I need the following attributes:

- Event Summary
- Start Date and Time
- End Date and Time
- Location

So far I managed to get the summary and location by sending a string in the form of `Event XYZ at Location ABC` but I am having trouble with the date format; I tried from and to, at and till, short date, long date, date first time first, etc. Any idea what the correct format is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the *Quick Add* parser isn't equipped to handle events that cross over midnight. As long as the event is in a single day, however, the hyphen works fine:

```
Dinner with Andre tomorrow 6p-9p
```

Dates work just as well:

```
Leftovers with Andre at Mom's 9/13 1:30p-3:30p
```

You can get things to cross over the "midnight barrier", but only if they're less than 24 hours. For instance:

```
Dessert with Andre 9/13 11p-3a
```

This will create an event that runs from 11:00 PM on September 13 to 3:00 AM on September 14.

What few tips there are for creating events with Quick Add can be found in [Google Calendar Support: Create an Event](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/72143).